# Popup Windows in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, qwidget

I am very new to programming and Qt so please be patient with my ignorance. I have spent two days searching for an answer and I can't figure out where to start.

I'm using Qt 4.8.5 and I would like to create a program that has a mainwindow with a few icons that will open frameless sub windows when clicked.

I've played with the window flags example but none of the options seem to meet my needs... the popup widget is close but I don't want the sub window to disappear when I click on something in the main window. All the other widgets like window and dialog cause the mainwindow to lose focus (not sure this is the right terminology).

Is there a way to make a popup window stay open until the icon is pressed again or use another kind of widget but keep focus on the main window?

I'm sorry if this question is poorly worded.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are asking, you could use `setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);` on the widget you wish to use as a popup window. It will give you an always on top frameless window.